# jquery .sortElements

Tags: jquery

I'm using this code

```
.wrapInner('<span title="sort this column"/>')
    .each(function () {

    var th = $(this),
        thIndex = th.index(),
        inverse = false;

    th.click(function () {

        table.find('td').filter(function () {

            return $(this).index() === thIndex;

        }).sortElements(function (a, b) {

            return $.text([a]) > $.text([b]) ? inverse ? -1 : 1 : inverse ? 1 : -1;

        }, function () {

            // parentNode is the element we want to move
            return this.parentNode;

        });

        inverse = !inverse;

    });

});
```

to try and get a table to order however I keep getting the following error

> TypeError: table.find("td").filter(function () {return $(this).index() === thIndex;}).sortElements is not a function

Does anyone have any clues?

Comment: Could you show us the code you're using?

Comment: What's the question here?  So, the example works?  What's "see below"?  What's `sortElements`?  Did you load all the necessary plugins?

Comment: (a) Is jQuery loaded? (b) Do you have the [sortElements plugin](https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/sortElements/) loaded? (c) Is `table` a jQuery object?

Comment: I don't see a `table` variable initialised in that code.

Comment: dam thought sort elements was included in the jquery base thanks

Answer (score 2):

[As said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419274/jquery-sortelements#comment18338179_13419274), you need the [jquery.sortElements.js plugin](https://github.com/padolsey/jquery.fn/tree/master/sortElements/).

Assuming the following markup:

```
<ul>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Carrot</li>
    <li>Apple</li>
</ul>
```

You could sort the items alphabetically like so:

```
$('li').sortElements(function(a, b){
    return $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? 1 : -1;
});
```

That would result in:

```
<ul>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Carrot</li>
</ul>
```

It also lets you specify what element will be sorted. The current collection's elements will be those referred to as a and b on each call of the comparator, but you might not want those elements to be the ones to move. E.g. you might want it to be a parent. For example, when sorting a table column, you would sort by the `<td>` elements, but the elements you actually want to move within the DOM are the `<tr>` (each `<td>`'s parent):

```
$('td').sortElements(myComparator, function(){
    // Return a reference to the desired element:
    return this.parentNode;
});
```

See more info here: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/.