# Whats wrong in this Html Table row sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a web page that contains an HTML table, and I want to sort the data when the click on the header.
I only want to use the vanilla javascript and the jquery API.

The complete `testpage.html` file.

```js
    var table = $('table');

    $('#facility_header, #city_header')
        .wrapInner('<span title="sort this column"/>')
        .each(function(){

            var th = $(this),
                thIndex = th.index(),
                inverse = false;

            th.click(function(){

                table.find('td').filter(function(){

                    return $(this).index() === thIndex;

                }).sortElements(function(a, b){

                    return $.text([a]) > $.text([b]) ?
                        inverse ? -1 : 1
                        : inverse ? 1 : -1;

                }, function(){

                    // parentNode is the element we want to move
                    return this.parentNode; 

                });

                inverse = !inverse;

            });

        });
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    **<style>**
        td, th { border: 1px solid #111; padding: 6px; }
        th { font-weight: 700; }
    **</style>**
</head>
<body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th id="facility_header">Facility name</th>
                <th>Phone #</th>
                <th id="city_header">City</th>
                <th>Speciality</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>CCC</td>
                <td>00001111</td>
                <td>Amsterdam</td>
                <td>GGG</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>JJJ</td>
                <td>55544444</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>MMM</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>AAA</td>
                <td>33332222</td>
                <td>Paris</td>
                <td>RRR</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I want that when anyone **clicks on the table header**, the table data get **sorted according to it**.

=============================== **Edit** ================================

**

```
    var table = $('table');

        $('#facility_header, #city_header')
            .wrapInner('<span title="sort this column"/>')
            .each(function(){

                var th = $(this),
                    thIndex = th.index(),
                    inverse = false;

                th.click(function(){

                    table.find('td').filter(function(){

                        return $(this).index() === thIndex;

                    }).sortElements(function(a, b){

                        return $.text([a]) > $.text([b]) ?
                            inverse ? -1 : 1
                            : inverse ? 1 : -1;

                    }, function(){

                        // parentNode is the element we want to move
                        return this.parentNode; 

                    });

                    inverse = !inverse;

                });

            });    
            jQuery.fn.sortElements = (function(){

var sort = [].sort;

return function(comparator, getSortable) {

    getSortable = getSortable || function(){return this;};

    var placements = this.map(function(){

        var sortElement = getSortable.call(this),
            parentNode = sortElement.parentNode,

            // Since the element itself will change position, we have
            // to have some way of storing its original position in
            // the DOM. The easiest way is to have a 'flag' node:
            nextSibling = parentNode.insertBefore(
                document.createTextNode(''),
                sortElement.nextSibling
            );

        return function() {

            if (parentNode === this) {
                throw new Error(
                    "You can't sort elements if any one is a descendant of another."
                );
            }

            // Insert before flag:
            parentNode.insertBefore(this, nextSibling);
            // Remove flag:
            parentNode.removeChild(nextSibling);

        };

    });

    return sort.call(this, comparator).each(function(i){
        placements[i].call(getSortable.call(this));
    });

};


})();

// end script
```

After changes the code it works better,
but sometimes this generates **wrong sorting flow** between **Capitalized word Vs only Small Letter Word**...

Comment: An error occurs at 'sortElements(-)' method...

Comment: It seems like you need an additional js file https://stackoverflow.com/a/20570452/1238244

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery .sortElements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419274/jquery-sortelements)

Comment: @lharby, This  helped me well, Thanks for help, but it doesn't sort perfectly,

Comment: I would recommend making a jsfiddle, and then at least other users on SO can contribute. Can you do that, or let us know if you need help setting one up.

Comment: When you're about to compare your words, put them all in lowercase with the `.toLowerCase()` method on both strings.